# Keycloak uma2 configuration with springboot 3.3.2 maven

Tags: java, spring, keycloak-rest-api

when i hitting the url it shows uma2.confoguration is missing in the server

I will get the below exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not obtain configuration from server [http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/SpringbootUserProject/.well-known/uma2-configuration].
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.<init>(AuthzClient.java:255) ~[keycloak-authz-client-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.create(AuthzClient.java:94) ~[keycloak-authz-client-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer.<init>(PolicyEnforcer.java:103) ~[keycloak-policy-enforcer-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer$Builder.build(PolicyEnforcer.java:662) ~[keycloak-policy-enforcer-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.integration.jakarta.ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.createPolicyEnforcer(ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.java:123) ~[keycloak-policy-enforcer-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.integration.jakarta.ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter$2.apply(ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.java:109) ~[keycloak-policy-enforcer-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.integration.jakarta.ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter$2.apply(ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.java:106) ~[keycloak-policy-enforcer-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Collections.java:2760) ~[na:na]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.integration.jakarta.ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.getOrCreatePolicyEnforcer(ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.java:106) ~[keycloak-policy-enforcer-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.integration.jakarta.ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.doFilter(ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter.java:71) ~[keycloak-policy-enforcer-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:362) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:308) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 404 / Not Found
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:103) ~[keycloak-authz-client-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$2.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:50) ~[keycloak-authz-client-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.<init>(AuthzClient.java:253) ~[keycloak-authz-client-22.0.0.jar:22.0.0]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.